# Plesk Laravel scheduler does not run

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduler

I have added the Laravel scheduler as a scheduled task to Plesk:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs && /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php artisan dailyCron:run >> /dev/null 2>& 1
```

But it is giving me an error:

```
Task "cd /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs &amp;&amp; /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php artisan dailyCron:run &gt;&gt; /dev/null 2&gt;&amp; 1" completed with error in 0 seconds, output:

'cd /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs && /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php artisan dailyCron:run >> /dev/null 2>& 1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
at (RunTime::Execute::commandLine line 611)
at Plesk impersonation(PipeServer::ServerThread::impersonateRunAs line 728)
```

Don't know why this error is coming up. Is anything wrong in the command?

Comment: btw, that isn't the task scheduler, that is just a random artisan command

Comment: Then how we can run artisan command through plesk scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

use a cronjob to excute a command on plesk panel

Comment: which cron command is that? I am using the command (mentioned in the question) in cron job "Scheduler" in plesk, but its not working. Can you show me the correct way?

Comment: hope this will help you. https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003121073-How-to-add-a-scheduled-task-in-Plesk-UI-using-crontab-syntax-

Comment: this dose not solves the issue. I am looking for the solution that can helpful for using artisan command of laravel in Scheduled tasks cron command.

Comment: php artisan dailyCron:run change it to php artisan schedule:run if not done by this please share your task scheduler code in question